# On closing xamarin view, i'm getting error: Cannot remove root page when it is also the currently displayed page

Tags: mvvmcross

I have a Xamarin.Forms app and use MVVMCross in it.
When I try to close a view and return a value, I'm getting the error:
Cannot remove root page when it is also the currently displayed page.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is Step6SignatureViewModel I'm trying to close:

```
    public class Step6SignatureViewModel : MvxViewModel, IMvxViewModel<string, string>
    {
        private readonly IMvxNavigationService _mvxNavigationService;

        public Step6SignatureViewModel(IMvxNavigationService mvxNavigationService)
        {
            _mvxNavigationService = mvxNavigationService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mvxNavigationService));
            CloseCommand = new MvxAsyncCommand(CloseView);
        }

        public void Prepare(string parameter)
        {
        }

        public IMvxAsyncCommand CloseCommand { get; set; }
        public TaskCompletionSource<object> CloseCompletionSource { get; set; }

        public async Task CloseView() {
            await _mvxNavigationService.Close(this, "filewithsignature.jpg");
        }
    }
```

Here is a command that opens up the Step6SignaturePage from the underline view model:

```
...
public IMvxAsyncCommand<string> SignCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new MvxAsyncCommand<string>(async (_) =>
                {
                    var model = await _mvxNavigationService.Navigate<Step6SignatureViewModel, string, string>(string.Empty);
                });
            }
        }
...
```

Here is a Page of "Step6SignatureViewModel":

```
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    [MvxContentPagePresentation(WrapInNavigationPage = true, NoHistory = true)]
    public partial class Step6SignaturePage : MvxContentPage<Step6SignatureViewModel>
    {
        public Step6SignaturePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

When I set WrapInNavigationPage = false, I don't get the error and get a result back, but it doesn't close the Step6SignaturePage.

Please advise! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I decided to not return my model. Instead of returning, I chose a unique filename where I save the signature.